# How to draw a one pixel wide UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios6, retina-display, quartz-2d

I'm running this code in the emulator set to iPhone (Retina 4-inch)

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor whiteColor]set];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
    UIBezierPath *vertLine = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [vertLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(20.5, 10.0)];
    [vertLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20.5, 20.0)];
    vertLine.lineWidth = 1.0;
    [[UIColor blackColor]set];
    [vertLine stroke];
}
```

I expect to have a one pixel vertical line, but the line the two pixel wide, and solid black.
The solid black color seems to suggest that this is not due to a problem with the alignment of the line on the pixel grid (it would be 50% gray in this case)

What's happening here ?

Comment: Try running it on the non-Retina-Emulator (iOS 5.1). I assume this might be how Retina-emulation looks like.

Comment: I have a two pixel wide line on Retina displays in the emulator, and a one pixel wide line on non Retina displays. The size of the emulator window matches the size of the emulated device (1136x640 for the iPhone for example). This is on iOS 6 and iOS simulator version 6.0 (358.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UIKit you don't specify pixels but points. Points are then mapped automatically to pixels. Your 1-point-width-line seems to be mapped to two retina-pixels.

See "Points versus Pixels" in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: Here is the sentence that solved my problem: *On a high-resolution display (with a scale factor of 2.0), a line that is one point wide is not antialiased at all because it occupies two full pixels (from -0.5 to +0.5). To draw a line that covers only a single physical pixel, you would need to make it 0.5 points in thickness and offset its position by 0.25 points. A comparison between the two types of screens is shown in Figure 1-4.*

Comment: Note this works for positioning non-bezier-path views, too, which allows you to avoid overriding drawRect:

`UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.contentView.frame.size.height - (1.0 - 0.25), self.contentView.frame.size.width)]]

lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(230.0/255.0f) green:(233/255.0f) blue:(237.0/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];

[self.contentView addSubview:lineView];`